# Running Jupyter notebook on fedora

Tags: jupyter-notebook, fedora

I've installed Jupyter Notebook on a Fedora 28 machine, using `anaconda`.

I am experiencing the most peculiar of problems: everything goes pretty smoothly, the notebook starts fine on my browser, but my kernels are not running, i.e. ipynb files give me a blank page. I do get a warning:

*404 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&delayStartupUntil=configured*

I've read the article 'Jupyter can’t start a kernel' on the official documentation and followed their instructions, from this link:

*http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#jupyter-can-t-start-a-kernel*

But, it doesn't seem to fix the problem, although I think the problem must reside somewhere around there.

I have installed Jupyter Notebooks on several other machines with no problem whatsoever.

Cheers, you guys!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo dnf install mathjax` fixed the issue for me in Fedora 28 package install (there are guides on how to do it at https://fedoralovespython.org/). They should have made mathjax a dependency in `sudo dnf install python3-notebook`.